# How to write chain command with parameter in Cypress?

Tags: angular, typescript, cypress

I'm trying to find an expander with its caption and click it.

When I'm doing it, it works:

```
cy.get('[caption="Radio Button"] > .expander-container').click();
```

I want to make this one as command.

```
Cypress.Commands.add('findExpanderByName', (Caption: string) => {
    cy.get('[caption=Caption] > .expander-container').click();
    cy.wait(2000);
});
```

And use it like this

```
cy.findExpanderByName("Radio Button");
```

However, it does not work cuz it **Caption** is not used as a variable.

How to get Caption variable value in command ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('findExpanderByName', (Caption: string) => {
    cy.get(`[caption=${Caption}] > .expander-container`).click();
    cy.wait(2000);
});
```

Comment: It gives error that unrecognized expression Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [caption={Caption}] > .expander-container

Comment: It's still having error : Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [caption=${Caption}] > .expander-container

Comment: Add your error screenshot. This should work. For your reference - https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/template-literal-types.html